# If my passport and Canadian visa expire in July can I still travel in April

Tags: visas, canada, visa-expiration, t-and-t-citizens

I am from Trinidad, my Trinidadian passport and Canadian visa both expire in July. Can I still travel to Canada in April, using both documents?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your passport and visa are both valid, you may travel to Canada.  Canada does not have a "six-month requirement" as many countries do.

Source: [CBSA](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html)

Note from the [US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html): "If you are transiting Canada en route to Europe, your passport must be valid for at least 3 months beyond your planned date of departure from the Schengen area."

[Flyertalk](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travelbuzz/1244452-traveling-canada-passport-expiring-4-months.html) agrees with the previous sources.

Based on [Dennis](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/38879/dennis)'s note: While Canada does not *require* six months validity, they will take extra steps.  They will (likely) issue you a visitor record, which is a document requiring you to be out of the country by a certain date.  This is because Canada needs for your passport to be valid at all times.

Receiving the Visitor Record requires a trip to Secondary Inspection at the border, which will take some time, depending on how busy they are.

Therefore, you have to consider: do you get a Visitor Record which will cost time from your holiday/travel plans *or* do you go get a new passport and avoid being taken for extra questioning?