# Expiration of passport one month after leaving Canada

Tags: visas, passports, canada, paperwork

Can I travel to Canada end of March to 4 April 2019 if my visa expires with my passport on 29 May 2019

Comment: Related: [If my passport and Canadian visa expire in July can I still travel in April](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110321/19400)

Comment: @phoog Except for the dates, this question is identical, as is the answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't vote to close because the other question is about a difference of three months while this is a difference of less than two months.  Or actually I closed the question with my visas-tag-gold-badge hammer and then thought that might be a bit much given the difference, so I reopened it.

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for the period of intended stay

SO yes, you can enter

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its possible.
Most countries require you to have a passport for valid for at least 3 months from departure from home country!

It varies on different countries and all but that's all I've researched about it.

Comment: Canada, however, is a country that lacks this requirement.